# Excel VBA: How to use early binding with class module in Personal workbook

Tags: excel, vba, class, late-binding, early-binding

I have a class module in my project that I want to make available to other projects. I moved the class module to my Personal workbook. Following [this Microsoft document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/troubleshoot/office-developer/set-up-vb-project-using-class), I added this function to the Personal workbook to be able to to create an instance of the class in other projects.

```
Option Explicit

Public Function new_video() As cVideo
    Set new_video = New cVideo
End Function
```

I can now create an instance in my project. However, to do so, I have to use late binding.

```
Dim Video As Object
Set Video = Application.Run("'personal.xlsb'!new_video")
```

This means I don't get the list of methods & properties once I type "Video."

According to the Microsoft doc linked above, it says

> Remember that to use the early binding code, the client project must
> include a reference (Tools | References…) to the Class Provider.xls
> file.

I have set a reference to PersonalMacros (the project name of the Personal workbook), but I don't see the workbook name itself (Personal.xlsb) in the list.

Is there something else I need to do or do I have to settle for late binding?

Comment: In what list do you try seeing the Personal.xlsb name?

Comment: @FaneDuru The list in Tools > References.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, in the Project Explorer window (Ctrl+R), make sure that you select the workbook in which you've added the reference.

Then select `Tools >> References`, and you should see `PersonalMacros` under the available references.

Then you can declare and create an instance of your class object using early binding as follows...

```
Dim video As PersonalMacros.cVideo
Set video = PersonalMacros.new_video
```

Also, make sure that the `Instancing` property in your class module is set to `2 - PublicNotCreatable`.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. When the MS doc said to use the filename, I didn't think of trying the project name.